# Sending push notifications with NSOutputStream returns -9844

Tags: ios, macos, push-notification

I'm trying to write OS X app sending push notifications with use of NSStreams. Everything seems to be fine but i get back error -9844 when sending data to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com. From SecureTransport.h

```
errSSLConnectionRefused     = -9844,    /* peer dropped connection before responding */
```

This is how I create and open output stream:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", 2195, &readStream, &writeStream);
self.outputPushStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[self.outputPushStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL                                forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
self.outputPushStream.delegate = self;
[self.outputPushStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[self.outputPushStream open];
```

And upon receiving NSStreamEventOpenCompleted event in NSStream delegate I send data:

```
const uint8_t *data = pushData.bytes;
[self.outputPushStream write:data maxLength:pushData.length];
```

I'm guessing that this may be some issue with certificates. I've got dev certificate and key for push notifications in keychain. I don't have any experience with SSL or NSStream so I don't really know where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if certificate in a keychain is enough for `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` to set up an ssl connection. I found [this](https://github.com/Ishaangandhi/PushController/blob/master/PushController/PushControllerAppDelegate.m) code which does pretty much the same you want to do, but it passes certificate with code (see `configureStreams` and `certificateArray` methods).